# Django - Externalize configurations to a JSON/YAML file

Tags: python, django, devops

We have a CI pipeline, which requires my Django project to externalize its configurations to a JSON or YAML file, instead of the usual settings.py.
One way to do this would be to parse the JSON/YAML file, and assign configurable values individually in settings.py, but that seems cumbersome, and introduces redundancy.

Please suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use package https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ
We are using it quite a long time in our project with CI (Jenkins).
So, you'll be able to create `.env` file with appropriate settings and inject them into your settings py like that:

```
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY', default='')
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', default=False)
...
```

In your CI setup, you will just inject variables appropriate for test build with environment plugins as first step of your build.